# Itô isometry for process that is not starting at 0?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Itô isometry states that 
$$
\int_0^t {X_sdW_s} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \int_0^t {X_s^2ds}\right)
$$
and my question is what is distribution of the process $I_T = \int_t^T {X_sdW_s}$? Is it maybe
$$
\int_t^T {X_sdW_s} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\int_t^T {X_s^2ds} \right)?
$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

$$
\int_t^T X_s dW_s = \int_0^T X_s dW_s - \int_0^t X_s dW_s
$$
and you know the distributions of them both, so the end result is clearly normal with zero mean. Can you figure out the variance?

Comment: Since we have two normal variables on the right-hand side, is distribution $N\sim\left( μ_1 - μ_2, σ_1^2 - σ_2^2\right)$? My confusion is that process $I_T$ starts at t, so the sample path is known up to the time t, and is, therefore, variance 0 for that term? Also, at time t, value for the process $X_t$ is known, so is, therefore, the expectation of the left-hand side equal to $X_t$, since $I_t$ is martingale?

Comment: @ITOM97 makes sense to me -- if $Y_{a,b}$ denotes your integral, then you have $Y_{0,t} + Y_{t,T} = Y_{0,T}$ where each term is a zero-mean normal and both terms on the LHS are independent...